# Como mudar o local do banco de dados

Tags: android, banco-de-dados

Estou criando um banco de dados como o `SqlOpenHelper` e sei que ele salva o banco de dados na pasta *date*. Queria saber se existe um jeito de mudar o local do banco de dados para o *sdcard* por exemplo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta passar o caminho completo (na classe `SQLiteOpenHelper`) ao invés de passar apenas o nome do banco de dados.

```
abstract class DatabaseManager extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String  DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final Integer DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    DatabaseManager(Context context) {
        super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Sua-Pasta/" + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isso deu certo ... me ajudou ... agr estou com outra duvida ... dar para eu criar uma pasta no mesmo endereço das pastas (layout, menu, drawable) e colocar meu banco la ?